# How to define function with usage context.log("My Log") and context.log.metric("MetricName", 123)

Tags: javascript, node.js

JavaScript experts!! I'm using the Node.js implementation of Azure functions, and I have a function something like the following:

```
module.exports = function (context, req) {

    context.log("Item failing on XXX"); 
    context.log.metric("XXX Failing", 1223); 
}
```

Now, im in the process of doing some unit tests locally which requires me to mock the context. I'm struggling to figure out how the context.log is defined to work as both a function `context.log()` and a static object `context.log.metric()`.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Paul

Comment: I can help only with jasmine unit tests.
If you have context as argument - just create mockObject yourself with needed mockFunctions:
var mockContext = {
 log: jasmine.createSpy('log')
};
mockContext.log.metric = jasmine.createSpy('log.metric');

And then just call module function with mockContext as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the feedback, figured it out the next morning with a clear head.

```
newEventgridContext(doneCallback) {

    var context = {
        body: {
            error: null
        },
        eventGridObject: {},
        done: function () {
            doneCallback(this);
        },

        bindings: {},
        log: function (msg) {
            console.log(msg)
        }
    }

    context.log["error"] = function(msg){
        console.error(msg)
    }

    context.log["metric"] = function(arg1, arg2){
        ...
    }

    return context
}
```

So now the usage `context.log("Message")` and `context.log.metric("Count",12)`